# How to implement if else functionality in SQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

I have an SQL query in which I have customer_id, User_id and name, the values will be provided from java class while calling the query.
The scenario here is, if I have customer_id then I should only consider customer_id and need not consider user_id and name, if customer_id is null then I have to consider user_id and if user_id id is null I have to consider name.

Right now, this logic is implemented in java if else statement. I want this logic to be moved to SQL query itself, following is the code:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE "
if(customer!=null && customer.length!=0)
      query = query+"AND CUSTOMER_ID LIKE '"+customer+"%'";
else if(user!=null && user.length!=0)
      query = query+"AND USER_ID LIKE '"user+"%'";
else if(name!=0 && name.length!=0)
      query = query + "AND NAME LIKE '"+name+"%'";
```

Comment: Can you be clear its mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Do you use JDBC? Or some else?

Answer (score 0):

Your constructed SQL has a minor flaw.

The conditional WHERE clauses begins with **AND**.  The only problem is the first one which passes looks like this **WHERE AND**

To fix it, simply have your WHERE start like this **WHERE 1=1**  (be sure to include the trailing space, and then you can add your remaining conditions

That said, you can create a stored procedure and pass 3 variables  @customer, @user, and @name

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE 1=1 
  AND CUSTOMER_ID LIKE Isnull(@customer,'')+'%'
  AND USER_ID LIKE isnull(@user,'')+'%'
  AND NAME LIKE isnull(@name,'')+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that using this sort of flexible logic in the SQL could impact the database's ability to choose a good execution plan.
http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/smart-logic

If the query is really quite a simple query like in the example then you might be better to stick with

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Customer"
if(customer!=null && customer.length!=0)
      query = query + " WHERE CUSTOMER_ID LIKE '"+customer+"%'";
else if(user!=null && user.length!=0)
      query = query + " WHERE USER_ID LIKE '"user+"%'";
else if(name!=0 && name.length!=0)
      query = query + " WHERE NAME LIKE '"+name+"%'";
```

so that each distinct query can be recognized by the database as following a different execution plan.

Otherwise, previous answer is correct except **1=1 AND** seems redundant.